# How do unified tracking with Google Analytics (app and web)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

We're users of Google Analytics on our organization. We've recently received an email from them saying that they're discontinuing **Google Analytics for App Reporting** next year (info [here])(https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2621230). At the moment we use Google Analytics on web and apps (android/ios) jointly.

I understand the focus of Firebase is apps, and having all Analytics information together for both Android and iOS.

My question is: is the previous SDK for apps going to disappear altogether?

What would be the standard approach from this point onwards if you also have a web? Add the Firebase SDK on apps, and track with Google Analytics for Firebase, and keep Google Analytics standard SDK on web? I believe this approach would be even more cumbersome since we'll need two interfaces to follow metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the email, it stated that by OCT 2019, data processing will stop and by Jan 2020, everything will be gone/inaccessible from GA. Hopefully, by then you'll have moved to Firebase Analytics.

GA is still the standard for web and that's not going away.

For Firebase, [you can use GTM with it](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/), maybe it might make maintenance easier.